# Chrome commands API browser back/forward shortcut key?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm taking a look Chrome commands API, the document says you can do control these keys for the chrome extension actions:

```
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y",
        "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+J"
      }
    },
```

But for what I want to implement, I need to overwrite shortcut key of "browser back/forward" moues key (button). Is that possible to code for that?

Comment: "shortcut key" means keyboard but then you say it's a mouse button. Please clarify.

Comment: As you know browser back/forward is mouse button, in general. You can search google image if you don't know. sorry for the ambiguous explanation.

Comment: No, a mouse button is a button on the actual mouse device. Some mouse devices have additional buttons used to perform a back/forward navigation by default. What you probably meant is a "button in the browser toolbar that can be clicked using a mouse", in which case the answer is no, extensions can't override that. But there is a workaround: use window.history.replaceState and pushState to override the navigation history inside a content script.

Comment: I didn't mean the clickable button on the chrome interface, I mean buttons on physical mouse device. Is this also not possible?

Comment: There's no extension API for this. If the click is performed within the content area of a web page then you can use a normal DOM event listener for `mousedown` in the extension's *content script*. Otherwise no, you'll have to use a separate utility or write it yourself.